# Существует ли эмулятор android 7 версии на пк?

Tags: android, эмулятор

Существует ли эмулятор android 7 версии на пк ?

Answer (score 2):

Да, существует. Например, [Genymotion](https://www.genymotion.com)

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]